# SQL Server Left Join and replace NULL value in VIEW with previous value

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server and I have two tables:

Table A

```
DATE         CUR     VALUE
----------------------------
2022-01-01   USD    18.253   
2022-01-02   EUR    20.21
2022-01-02   USD    19.23
2022-02-02   TRY    16.12
2022-02-10   TRY    15.12
2022-02-11   USD    13.321
```

Table B

```
DATE         CUR     AMOUNT
----------------------------
2022-01-03   USD    100   
2022-01-06   EUR    125   
2022-02-10   TRY    110
2022-02-12   USD    112
```

I try to create a view using `LEFT JOIN` to get this result :

```
DATE         CUR    AMOUNT  VALUE 
-----------------------------------
2022-01-03   USD     100    19.23
2022-01-06   EUR     125    20.21
2022-02-10   TRY     110    15.12
2022-02-12   USD     112    13.321
```

The value column in view is from Table A and if is Null it should be the previous value according to previous DATE and CUR columns.

This is my query:

```
SELECT B.DATE, B.CUR, B.AMOUNT, A.VALUE 
FROM TABLE_A B
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A A ON A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.CUR = B.CUR
```

But I got these results :

```
DATE         CUR    AMOUNT  VALUE 
-----------------------------------
2022-01-03   USD     100    NULL
2022-01-06   EUR     125    NULL
2022-02-10   TRY     110    15.12
2022-02-12   USD     112    NULL
```

Comment: `QUANTITY` might be a more helpful name than `AMOUNT`, just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query adds some confusion because you're desired results are from `Table_B` not `Table_A` and your `Amount` and `Value` columns are in the *opposite* tables.

Ignoring that however and just looking at your sample data and desired results, you can retrieve the `VALUE` from `Table_A` using a *correlated subquery*:

```
select [date], cur, amount, (
  select top(1) [value] 
    from Table_A a 
    where a.cur = b.cur and a.[date] <= b.[date] 
    order by [date] desc
) [Value]
from Table_B b;
```

Comment: It work but when i used OUT APPLY thank you

Comment: Yes the same correlation can work in an outer apply.